# How to join two bones that are part of the same armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

after looking for a solution all the day,I surrendered. I would like to know how to join two disconnected bones that are part of the same armature.

[image: pic 1]

I tried to select the two points of the bones and then pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to complete the gap but they don't stick. Check here what happens :

[image: pic with F key]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FILE BLEND

[image]

Here some shots of the final result

[image]

[image]

In order

**1)** In Edit Mode I select boneA and press alt + f in order to switch its direction (as you can see is the only bone having the opposite direction respect the others bone of the tail of your bird)

**PS remember when you use alt + f your bone will switch direction AND will lose every connection with the other bones**; for this reason i will do step number 4) and number 5)

**2)** I take the boneA and i move its "head" near to the tail of boneB

**3)** Now I follow the step i tell you before:  select boneB - press shift - select boneA (remember the order is important); in this way you'll have both bones selected.

**4)** Press Ctrl + P and click Connected

**5)** In the end to keep your boneA connected with your bird's tail (i.e. the boneC and the others) i add a Copy Location in boneA

[image]

Comment: thanks man. I tried to do what you said,but it didn't work. you can see what happened here : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-19_22-17-55.png and here : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-19_22-18-30.png ; what can I do ?

Comment: Ok i understand! Please upload your file. I need to check the armature

Comment: sure : http://psychonews.it/dati/Pierino78.blend

Comment: I edit my question; tell me if it's what are you looking for

Comment: check this picture : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-20_00-08-31.png. I see that you haven't joined one bone with the upper one,but anyway I see that there is a dashed line. What's the difference between a dashed link and a non dashed link ? thanks...

Comment: It's a different way to connect 2 bones (and it's very quickly) but comments are not the place to answer a question like that; if you need more info ask directly a question in the site and we will answer as soon as. Furthermore if my answer reply and clarify your doubt about your armature please tick the answer as correct in order to check this problem as solved